# print @customer[:group_name] can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to print customer[:group_name] in my rails app, but I am having trouble.

controller:

```
def index
  @customers = [
    {
        :name => 'James',
        :group_name => 'Latin@ Social Work Coalition',
    }
  ]
end
```

html.erb:

I tried this:

```
    <%= @customers[:group_name] %>
    ERROR: can't convert Symbol into Integer

    <%= customer[:group_name] %>
    ERROR: undefined local variable or method `customer' for #<  
    <Class:0x000001017d2f10>:0x00000103198378>
```

But when I do this:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
    <%= customer[:group_name] %>
<% end %>
```

it works, but I don't want to each do because there is only one.

What is the best way to print this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something like this in your erb file:

```
<%= @customers.first[:group_name] %>
```

You're accessing an array first, then the hash

Or

You can change your controller to:

```
@customer = 
{
  :name => 'James',
  :group_name => 'Latin@ Social Work Coalition',
}
```

and the view to:

```
<%= @customer[:group_name] %>
```